# How do we output a Panda dataframe via Python for use as a .csv?

Tags: python, pandas, output

What's the quickest way to output a Panda dataframe via Python for use as a .csv?

My output is called 'dframe' and it is really simple. Here is some code for context:

dframe = df.head()

Comment: `df.to_csv(path)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dframe.to_csv(r'your path')
```